# Why is my multiprocessing slower than that shown on youtube?

Tags: python, performance, debugging, multiprocessing, multiprocess

```
import time
import multiprocessing


def do_something():
    print("sleep 1 second")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Done sleeping...")

if __name__ =='__main__':
    start = time.perf_counter()
    processes = []
    for _ in range(10):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something)
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)

    for process in processes:
        process.join()
    finish = time.perf_counter()

    print(f'Finished in {round(finish-start, 2)} second(s)')
```

Above is my code, what I'm trying to do is to do multiprocessing and the thing is my code ended up running for 1.22 seconds where the guy on youtube only takes 1.02 seconds! I'm using pycharm (python 3.9) and I check my task manager that when I'm running this code, my cpu utilization is not to the maximum and so is my memory. Is it because I'm using a laptop not a desktop? does my computre hardware affect the speed? The 0.2 seconds mean a lot to me as I'm doing a project and a spit of second matters.

Or is it because I used `if __name__ =='__main__':` but the problem is if I don't use this line, my code wouldn't run at all but the guy that is in the video is able to run his code without this line (I checked and I don't have any other files open, the only one that I have is `main.py` which is shown above. I personally doesn't think that would affect the speed but if it does please tell me.

The youtube video that I'm talking about is Corey Schafer's "Python Multiprocessing Tutorial: Run Code in Parallel Using the Multiprocessing Module"

Video: [Python Multiprocessing Tutorial: Run Code in Parallel Using the Multiprocessing Module](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fKl2JW_qrso&t=859s)

You can see at 14:09 that it takes only 1.02 seconds for him to run the code

Answer (score 1):

Of course, the hardware matters a lot in running times, especially when using multiprogramming. It depends on the number of cores, hyperthreading possibility, CPU frequency, and memory.

Comment: While what you say may be true the a very general sense, I don't think it applies in this case because the task is merely sleeping for a relatively large amount of time — which cancels most of those considerations out,

Comment: @martineau Even though there are fewer lines of code, it needs that processing power to invoke the pvm, gc and to import the modules and all the preprocessing stuff

Comment: I don't think that's enough to account for the difference — it's probably because the OP is using Windows and the guy in the video isn't (and the way separate processes are started in the OSs).

Answer (score 1):

`if __name__ == "__main__"` is needed for spawning operating systems like Windows, not for forking systems like linux. Windows is a little slower running new Process because it needs to execute a new python and pickle/explode the environment from the calling process, while linux just forks and gives a different view to the memory. I wouldn't be suprised it that's a lot of your extra .2 seconds. Notice this is a one time thing so if your process has a lot of work to do, no big deal.

Although the number of processes matter generally, since the only work is `sleep(1)`, you'd need to make many processes for that to matter.

I don't know if pycharm has anything to do with it. It would be worth testing on your command line to see.

I ran on my linux laptop at 1.01 seconds. When I forced "spawn" mode like on Windows, that went up to 1.11 seconds. So, .1 second overhead for spawn for me.

**UPDATE**

Considering that the processes are created serially and that's where the extra time is spent, I tried to parallelize that part of the operation with in-process threads. First I tried a thread pool, but that was too slow, but just having a thread create the process sped the code up to running in about a second, squashing that .1 second (.2 second in your case) disadvantage.

```
import time
import multiprocessing
import threading

def do_something():
    print("sleep 1 second")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Done sleeping...")

def run_do_something():
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something)
    p.start()
    processes.append(p)

if __name__ =='__main__':
    multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')
    start = time.perf_counter()
    threads = []
    processes = []
    for _ in range(10):
        t = threading.Thread(target=do_something)
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

    for process in processes:
        process.join()
    finish = time.perf_counter()

    print(f'Finished in {round(finish-start, 2)} second(s)')
```

Comment: wait a sec, you didn't even call the run_do_something in your program, and if I'm right you are using only threading not multiprocessing? Please correct me if I'm wrong